Is there any way to share same API response data between "generateMetadata" method and Page Component's method in NextJS 13.5 App Router Page
I have written code similar to this
async function getPostData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.example.com/post')
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
  return res.json()
}

calling this Method inside generateMetadata method like
export async function generateMetadata(props : Props) {
  const postData = await getPostData();
}

and the same getPostData method calling inside the Page Component Method like
const PostPage = async (props: Props) => {
   const postData = await getPostData();
}

So, I want to know, Is there any way to share the same response data between both Method generateMetadata and PostPage without caching the API response.

Does this answer  your question?

Does this answer your question? Set Metadata Dynamically Without Duplicate Requests - NextJS 13
